# nodejs "undefined" when stringifying Mongoose object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose

in my code i have following console logs:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(department.locationFilter, null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(department.locationFilter.geoLocation, null, 2));
```

The first log results in:

```
{
  "city": "Stuttgart",
  "radius": 50,
  "geoLocation": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      9.1800132,
      48.7784485
    ]
  }
}
```

The second log results in:

```
undefined
```

When i log `"geoLocation" in department.locationFilter` it also results in `false`.

I don't understand why the geoLocation is `undefined` because it exists inside the JSON object.

For some more information, the department is read from mongodb.

Comment: Do you use Mongoose? Because Mongoose is famous for generating weird and immutable objects. What you log is not necessarily JSON as you think but some of Mongoose's weirdos. Try to convert the Mongoose object to regular, plain object first : `department = department.toObject()` then try again

Comment: Does `geoLocation` have any invisible whitespace characters?

Comment: Is `geoLocation` available in all records?

Comment: Yes i'm using mongoose. There are no whitespaces

Comment: @JeremyThille your tip works. I'll accept it as answer. Strange thing because city and radius work, but geoLocation not

Comment: Nice, posted it as an answer then :) Mongoose gave me enough headaches...

Comment: GeoLocation has to be a 2dSphere index, hence the weirdness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose is famous for generating weird and immutable objects. What you log is not necessarily JSON as you think but some of Mongoose's weirdos. Try to convert the Mongoose object to regular, plain object first : `department = department.toObject()`.

Also, if you need only the data and not a full Mongoose object, you can query using `.lean()` :

`Model.find({}).lean()`

You'll get simple objects out of the box, and lean() is faster.